# Whats the difference of an classic queue with and without x-queue-type: classic in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

When creating a queue in the RabbitMQ UI with de default options, it shows in the features column `D` for durable, and `Args` with `x-queue-type: classic`.

When creating it by code, you can create like this in python:
`channel.queue_declare('QueueName', durable=True)`, but it is different from the queue created by the UI, without the `Args` feature of `x-queue-type: classic`, but it's type is a classic queue as indicated.

In python, you can create a queue that is just like the one created by default in the UI with this:
`channel.queue_declare('QueueName', durable=True, arguments={'x-queue-type':'classic'})`

My doubt is, since both queue types are classical, whats the difference between the one with the argument `x-queue-type: classic` and the one without, assuming all rest is the same?

In this image an example as shown in the RabbitMQ UI:
[image: image example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the new RabbitMQ versions, there are different types of queues.

- Classic queues ( the classic queues RabbitMQ has for a while)
- Quorum queues ( [Type of queues available from rabbitmq 3.8](https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html))
- Streaming queues ( [released >= 3.9](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/tree/master/deps/rabbitmq_stream))

When you declare a queue using a client, if you don't specify anything the server automatically tag the queues with  `x-queue-type: classic`

> My doubt is, since both queue types are classical, whats the difference between the one with the argument x-queue-type: classic and the one without, assuming all rest is the same?

It is the same